# Cloning and pushing using SSH key suddenly not working

Tags: git, github

Yesterday I tried to clone a repo which I have been successful in doing many times before, but now get the error (this also happens when I try to push):

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried adding the public key again to my github account, but it says the key already exists. My global git config file is as follows:

```
[user]
        email = email@account.com
        name = my name

[core]
        editor = nano
```

I haven't modified anything in regards to my git or github. I set up my SSH key to not use a passphrase. I am on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Someone left a comment with that exact solution and then deleted it lol.